# How to get month number by week number? Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a column with weeknumbers incrementing from 1 to 42.
Next to it I would like to have the corresponding monthnumbers from 1 to 12.
So e.g. next to week 1, 2, 3 it would be month 1.

How would I achieve this in google sheets?

[image: This is what it looks like]

Best
Florian

Comment: _“So e.g. next to week 1, 2, 3 it would be month 1.”_ - and next to week 4, and 5 as well, at least for 2018 …?

Comment: There seems to be objects and method for working with dates available, https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en - but I can’t spot one to create a date object by giving only year and week, so you might need to go about this the other way around - start by creating dates in some sort of loop, and then check what week/month you are in …

Comment: Actually this is do-able if you put in (say) October/November for week 44 etc. Perhaps you could fill in for the first few weeks how you would like the month to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A week number may span a month end, so two different months for different days in the *same* week. ie

> Not possible.

Comment: Nice catch! I guess if OP asked for the month at (say) the beginning of a certain week, there would be a unique answer.

Comment: Hm... not that keen on November and December anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible if you'll count concrete dates.

A1:

`=ARRAYFORMULA( (ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&42)) - 1) * 7 + today())`

- adjust the date, change `today()` to your start date.

B1:

`=FILTER(WEEKNUM(A1:A,1),A1:A<>"")`

- adjust week type if needed, change `1`

C1:

`=FILTER(MONTH(A1:A),A1:A<>"")`

[image]